# How to make a function loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make function non() loop after 10 clicks. I've looked at other sources to help me do it but they didn't work. When i click the non button 10 times it shows an alert and when i click it 10 more times the alert dosen't appear. The loop needs to function every time the non button gets clicked 10 times. Here is my code.

```js
 var click = 9;
            function non(){
                var i;
                var message= document.getElementById("message");
        
        //Affiche un message chaque fois que le bouton non est cliquer
                for(i=0; i<1; i++) {
                message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!<br>";
                
                }
                
                if(!(click--)){
                    alert("Es-tu près");
                    non();
                    

                }
                document.getElementById("boutonNon").click;
                
            }
```

```css
   
.titre{
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #498efd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.bouton{
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    

}
.boutonOui{
   background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234); 
}

.boutonOui:hover{
    background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
.paspres{
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    
    


    padding-top: 5px;    
    padding-left: 30px;    
    height: auto;
    background-color: #cecece;
    max-width: 740px;
    max-height: 15s00px;
    border-radius: 45px;
}
.question{
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <h1 class="titre">Quiz Vocabulaire</h1>
            <div id="hide1">    
                <div class="paspres">
                    <br>Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!
                    <div id="message"></div><br>
                 </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="question" id="hide2">
            <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonOui" onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'">Oui</button>
            <div id="divNon">
                <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonNon" onclick="non()" value="reset">Non</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Don't click the yes button since it leads to another part of the quiz which i've not included and makes the the code preview a blank page.

Comment: So, everytime you click it it should append at the message. And after 10, 20, 30, etc. times it should show the alert?

Comment: Yes, every 10 clicks the alert should popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never reset the value of `click`.  So it just continues into negative numbers indefinitely, which are never "falsey".

Simply reset the value (to 10 this time, since you immediately decrement it anyway by re-invoking the function) when showing the alert:

```
if(!(click--)){
  alert("Es-tu près");
  click = 10;
  non();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need recursion?

```
let clickCounter=1;
onClick(){
  if (clickCounter%10===0) {
     alert('tenth click!')
  }
 clickCounter+=1;
  //other onclick functionality
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulo-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Modulo) (a % b) to achieve that:

```js
let click = 0;
  function non() {
    const message= document.getElementById("message");    
    
    //Affiche un message chaque fois que le bouton non est cliquer                   
    message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!<br>";
                
    click++;
    if (click % 10 === 0) {
      alert("Es-tu près");
      non();
    }

    document.getElementById("boutonNon").click;
  }
```

```css
.titre{
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #498efd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.bouton{
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    

}
.boutonOui{
   background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234); 
}

.boutonOui:hover{
    background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
.paspres{
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1 class="titre">Quiz Vocabulaire</h1>
  <div id="hide1">    
    <div class="paspres">
    <br>Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!
    <div id="message"></div>
    <br>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="question" id="hide2">
  <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonOui" onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'">Oui</button>
  <div id="divNon">
    <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonNon" onclick="non()" value="reset">Non</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add click = 9 to your if statement

```js
var click = 9;
            function non(){
                var i;
                var message= document.getElementById("message");
        
        //Affiche un message chaque fois que le bouton non est cliquer
                for(i=0; i<1; i++) {
                message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!<br>";
                
                }
                
                if(!(click--)){
                    alert("Es-tu près");
                    click = 9
                    non();
                    

                }
                document.getElementById("boutonNon").click;
                
            }
```

```css
.titre{
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #498efd;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.bouton{
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    

}
.boutonOui{
   background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234); 
}

.boutonOui:hover{
    background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);
}
.paspres{
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    
    


    padding-top: 5px;    
    padding-left: 30px;    
    height: auto;
    background-color: #cecece;
    max-width: 740px;
    max-height: 15s00px;
    border-radius: 45px;
}
.question{
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
            <h1 class="titre">Quiz Vocabulaire</h1>
            <div id="hide1">    
                <div class="paspres">
                    <br>Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!
                    <div id="message"></div><br>
                 </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="question" id="hide2">
            <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonOui" onclick="window.location.href='jeu_educatifs2.html'">Oui</button>
            <div id="divNon">
                <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonNon" onclick="non()" value="reset">Non</button>
            </div>
            </div>
```